# Why do I get "Synonym 'syn.Syn_AAA' refers to an invalid object" Error?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute a stroed procedure it works. But specifically when I run the select statement I get the following error

> Synonym 'syn.Syn_NEO_DB_tGradeAliases' refers to an invalid object.

```
SELECT  
            aa.CompanyId [LegCompanyId],
            aa.ProductId AS [LegGradeId],
            aa.GradeAliasId [LegGradeAliasId],
            aa.ProductName AS [LobGradeText],
            aa.[Alias] [GradeAlias],
            aa.PhraseKey [PhraseKey],
            GETUTCDATE() AS 'TimeStamp'
    FROM    syn.Syn_AAA aa
```

I haven't done any database change/permission change.
How can I overcome this?

I ran following query and it shows the base_object_name correctly linked to my table.

> SELECT *  FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'Syn_AAA'

Comment: try removing the alias `aa`  just do a `select * FROM  Syn_AAA`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu same error //Invalid object name Syn_AAA//

Comment: Is `syn` your schema name? Synonyms need a schema name while they are being referred to!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer yes it is schema..No issue with that

Comment: @ASP If i run like //SELECT *  FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'syn.Syn_AAA'// im not getting any result. WIthout 'syn' i get the tbale info. But all my database objects run with schema (more than 300) we haven't faced any issue with schema

Comment: Can you check your underlying table exists that synonym referring?

Comment: Just can you try to run the select statement for your table?  Even though the base table has reference the synonym, table can be deleted without removing synonym in SQL Server.

Comment: @ASP Yes I can, the table in the other server, we have created symlinks to that server

Comment: If this is dev box then try with drop and recreate synonym

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170643/discussion-between-asp-and-ratha).

Comment: could be a permissions issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame by replacing synonym with  [LINKED_SERVER].[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[OBJECT_NAME].